# PHP Check if dynamic named folder exists

Tags: php, file

I'm having problems checking if a dinamically named folder exists using php. I know i can use

```
file_exists()
```

to check if a folder or file exists, but the problem is that the name of the folders I'm checking may vary.

I have folders where the first part of the name is fixed, and the part after "_" can vary. As an example:
folder_0, 
where every folder will start with "folder_" but after the "_" it can be anything.

Anyway i can check if a folder with this property exists?

Thanks in advance.
SR

Comment: you can check it like this => "file_exists('dir/folder_'.$i)" or is_dir('dir/folder_'.$i)

Comment: To use that approach i would need to know what $i is, but i don't know, it can be anything, it's created dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a loop to go through all the files/folders in the parent folder:

```
$folder = '/path-to-your-folder-having-subfolders';
$handle = opendir($folder) or die('Could not open folder.'); 
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
    if (preg_match("|^folder_(.*)$|", $file, $match)) {
        $curr_foldername = $match[0];
        // If you come here you know that such a folder exists and the full name is in the above variable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function find_wildcard_dirs($prefix)
{
   return array_filter(glob($prefix), 'is_dir');

}
```

e.g.

```
print_r(find_wildcard_dirs("/tmp/santos_*'));
```